# Using "a tiny" in the same way as "a little"

Tags: word-usage

Saying

> That made me a little happier

is clearly perfectly fine, yet no one would really ever say

> That made me a tiny happier,

even though both "little/tiny bit happier" are fine.

Is there some logic to this? It's perfectly clear what the second sentence means, even though it sounds "a tiny" wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to what Matt Эллен said, but uses the analysis and terminology of the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*. First, *tiny* is only ever an adjective. As such it can function as attributive modifier of nouns (e.g. *a **tiny** flower*) or predicative complement of verbs (e.g., *that flower is **tiny***), and a few other minor functions.

The situation with little is similar when it's an adjective, but it's not just an adjective. We also have the determinative *little* (e.g., *little water*) and the complex determinative *a little* (e.g., *a little water*; a complex determinative is a single determinative made up of two or more words.) Determinatives typically function as determiner of nouns (e.g., ***that*** water), but some determinatives also function as modifier of adjectives (e.g., *it wasn't **that** big*). Most adjectives, *tiny* included, can't function as modifier of adjectives. Also, some NPs can modify adjective (e.g., [*a city block*] *longer*).

```
That made me [a little] happier
```

D *a little* is modifier of Adj *happier*

```
*That made me tiny happier
```

Adj *tiny* can't modify Adj *happier*

```
*That made me a tiny happier
```

D *a* can't form a constituent with Adj *tiny* or Adj *happier*; Adj *tiny* still can't modify Adj *happier*

```
a bit
```

D *a* is determiner of N *bit* forming an NP

```
That made me [a bit] happier
```

NP *a bit* is modifier of Adj *happier*

```
a little/tiny bit
```

D *a* is determiner of N *bit*; Adj *little*/*tiny* is modifier of N *bit*

```
That made me [a little/tiny bit] happier
```

NP *a little*/*tiny bit* is modifier of Adj *happier*

The interesting question is how *little* became a determinative and how *a little* became a complex determinative.

Comment: So you agree that *a little* in "a little happier" is a NP that modifies the adj. "happier". Would you thus agree that "a tininess" would work the same way as "a little"? Or do you think "a tininess" is wrong/do you think "tininess" isn't even a word?

Comment: No, "a little" in "a little happier" is a complex determiner, not an NP.

Comment: Thank you for writing this, it's the clearest explanation yet.

Comment: In that case, you should edit or explain the last part: "'That made me [a little/tiny bit] happier'(.)
NP a little/tiny bit is modifier of Adj happier"

Comment: Not sure what your point is AverageGatsby. 'Tiny/Little' is an adjective functioning as a modifier in the larger NP 'a little bit'.

Answer (score 8):

Quite simply "a little" is used as an adverb and a determiner, but "a tiny" is not used at all.

Both *little* and *tiny* are used as adjectives.

Comment: So, in **a little bit closer** and **a tiny bit closer**, 'little' and 'tiny' function as adjectives, describing 'bit'. In **a little closer** 'a little' is an adverb. Phew!!  A subgroup of adverbs called 'intensifiers'?

Comment: so are you suggesting that "little" in "a little happier" works as an adverb or adjective? because it does not. it has to be a noun in this case as the "a" would otherwise be very awkward. Additionally "it made me little happier" conveys something different. For the rest; comment section of dan's answer. you guys maybe do answer the specific question as in "can one use *a tiny*?". BUt I am not sure about the generall grammar of "a little" and the possibility of "a tininess". Shall i ask a new question?

Comment: I am saying that "a little" is an adverb, made up of two words. Hence no "a tiny". Compare "a little" to *somewhat*.

Comment: The fact that "a little" is an adverb(ial phrase) is really not the point. First off all it is obvious. Secondly: The fact that "little" in this phrase is a noun and you trie to substitude it with the ADJECTIVE "tiny" is maybe worth a look. THIS is what i am suggesting if I say What about "a tininess happier". Dan's comment section for elaboration.

Comment: I am not suggesting anything about the state of "little" in the adverb "a little". The question asks about why "a little happier" works, but "a tiny happier" doesn't. If the adverb nature of the phrase was obvious to the asker, they wouldn't have asked. You can try to break down "a little" but I think you'll be banging your head against a wall.

Comment: Note that _a little happier_ is synonymous with _a little bit happier_, or _happier, by a little bit_, where _a little bit_ is an idiom for 'a small increment or decrement'. In other words, _a little (bit)_ is a quantifier, and the _bit_ part is often dropped. _A tiny_, on the other hand, is not a quantifier, nor even a constituent; it's an article followed by an adjective that hasta modify a count noun with proportions and dimensions (_tiny_ means the dimensions are much smaller than usual, though the proportions are more or less the same).

Comment: _A tiny_ can be part of _a tiny bit_, another quantifier. _She's a tiny bit happier_ is fine. But it's not an idiom, so you can't just delete the _bit_ part, which is what marks it as a quantifier. In other words, _tiny_ hasn't been bleached of its meaning and become part of the automatic syntactic machinery nearly as much as _little_ has.

Comment: @JohnLawler Some of my friends use *a tiny* without a following *bit*. Here's some news stories with [a tiny more](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=oJvHVIaQNeqq8weAx4KgAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a+tiny+more%22&tbm=nws)

Comment: Evidence that it's following the same idiomizing path as _bit_. Wait a few decades.

Comment: @JohnLawler Btw, I saw that you made an edit to [my post here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223990/that-vs-which-vs-what/224015#224015) and then deleted it. Please feel free to improve my offering. Was a bit of a speed post and I'm sure it could do with some tweaking!

Comment: I deleted the commas in the example sentences, before I read the rest of the post, which points out that they're wrong. TL;DR. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that "happier" is a (comparative) adjective

and

"a little" is a compound predicative intensifier which acts on that.

"A tiny", however, is not a compound intensifier of any kind, but a determiner plus an adjective, despite the fact that "tiny" and "little" are synonymous in their simple adjectival forms.

In other words, "a" and "little", can be put together to create an intensifier, while "a" and "tiny" cannot, despite the similarity of meaning between "little" and "tiny".

Comment: And now; if you additionally can give a canonical answer to the question whether or not we may use "a tininess" in the same way we use "a little" (which i sadly wasn't allowed to implement), then I submit the bounty willingly. Concerning the contruction of "a little" your answer doesn't seem very elaborate while saying it is an intensifier strikes rather vague. Expacially if we keep in mind that in the complete wikipedia article about intensifiers "a little" is not to be found. The same goes for the next 3 pages which pop up if you google "intensifier".

Answer (score 0):

Little has (at least) two senses.  One of these is quite close (but larger!) than tiny.

A little dog is a small dog.  A tiny dog is an even smaller dog.

However, a little upset means quite upset (i.e. somewhere between very upset and not upset at all). In this sense little is understood to lie within a range of possible amounts.  It is comparative.  Tiny is not a relative measure in this sense.  It is absolute.

Comment: I think this comes closer than the answer by Joe Blow but neither is the real/finite answer. The actually question is why we drop the "bit" from the phrase "a little/tiny bit" only if we use "little". This could be because we have accepted "a little" as a noun - a small amount - while "a tiny" just isn't a word. As i also mentioned in a comment to the question: while i can't cope with "it made me a tiny happier" I could imagine "it made me a tininess happier". this is though to vague to convince me.

Comment: This is irrelevant, Dan.  The reason you can't say "a tiny happier" (or indeed "many milk") is **the countable issue**

Comment: I'm trying to follow you @Joe Blow.  I think you are saying that little is for uncountables (cf less) and tiny is for countables (cf fewer). So, you say, a little milk and a little happier.

Comment: sure, for "fluids", you can say a little air, a little petrol, a little milk.  for "countables", you can say a tiny building, a tiny computer, a tiny object.  that's all there is to this question from the OP - it's amazing there has been so much written on it !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this. Although I can say 'a little dog' and 'a tiny dog', I can say 'a little sad' but not 'a tiny sad'. An attractively straight-forward answer says simply that 'little' may be used with both countable and uncountable quantities. It seems to me that this answer misses a comparative nuance in the 'uncountable' use of little. Little can be an adjective meaning 'small' (not big).  It can also act as an intensifier meaning somewhere between big and small. There is a clue that little has two senses - little as an intensifier is always preceded by 'a'

So 'little' as an adjective describes a noun - a little dog (not a big, fat or silly one).

'a little' is an intensifier that modifies the, er, intensity of an adjective.  How tired are you ? -  a little, quite, very, Zzzzz ...

Comment: This is the same answer as the other 2 tried to provide, I am not the OP, but I would wish for a more thorough answer which keeps in mind that quite a few dictionaries define "a little" as a noun and at the same time as an idiom, while other dictionaries define it as a determinative, both definitions consent to the meaning "*a small amount of*". ***Additionally*** to give a correct answer one would need to address the issue that "happier" is not a noun, but an adjective (comperative) linking back to "me". *Thus* a determinator is by common definition not the case. It seems adverbial. TL;NS

Comment: While little is a noun, an adj, and an adv (+a little ~ determinat/idiom) at the same time, tiny is neither a noun nor an adverb and i would thus strongly advice against saying "a tiny happier". I see "a little happier" in the same logical sense as "a pint of beer" just that the of is missing. (the same applies to a better example) So I think the component "**little** of this adverbial phrase is a NOUN. This would raise the question whether "a tininess happier" would be correct/more acceptable or not.

Comment: In the end you describe "little" as an intesifier which is an interesting idea i haven't seen untill now. Equal how it would more correctly be a *diminisher/diminutive* as fumblefingers has stated in the comments. NEVERTHELESS, i still do not think that this explains the given case as a diminutuve would look like this: "It made me little happier", which seems to lessen the amount of gained happiness further if not *denie*  it. "a little" seems still to be something else.

Comment: Please see extra added to answer above.  'A little' is one of a range adjectival modifiers, used especially with comparative adjectives.  How close are we to solving this problem ? - a little closer, quite a lot closer, almost there.

Comment: Possibly almost there. It might jsut be that I am to obsessed about the idea of "a tininess" to give the author of the question what he wants. I am though becoming more and more convinced of the fact that we can use "a tininess" as an abstract measurement of size/volume/amount the same way we use "a little" as an abstract measurement of size/amount/volume.

Comment: I.e. 1."a little (n.); A small/"little" amount or *abstract measurement* of. 2."a little"(adj.modifier/adv./idiomatic)*: used to intensify/regulate** an adj. as in "you are made an abstract yet comparibly little measurement happier. Hence, (atleast if we accept tininess as an existing nount): A tininess (n.); a very small/tiny amount or *abstr.msrm* of.  a tininess (adj.modifier/adv)*; used to intensify/regulate/modify** an adj by a tiny abstr.msrm. as in: ***you are made an abstrakt yet comparibly tiny measurement happier.***

Comment: * these terms are to be discussed as they elude the main issue. **If** "a tininess" is acceptable to use in the given way, ***"a little" would not be idiomatic***. On the other side **if it would not be** acceptable to use, "a little" in the given form and usage ***would be idiomatic***. Atleast this is what my logic tells me.

Comment: ** i would suggest the use of the word regulate instead of intensify as they in my eyes do not add to something but seem to set the value/the amount of it, just as a numerical/quantitatif determinant would.

Comment: Please tell me my understanding of "a little" is not totally screwed.

Comment: This makes makes me "a few" sad.

Answer (score 0):

While tiny has a negligible connotation, little has a comparative (definitely not/non negligible) connotation.  It is also why little is more prevalently used with adjectives than tiny.  'It made me a little happy' is common than 'It made me a tiny happy'.  To put it in another perspective, 'tiny' is used to just say 'not zero', while 'little' is used to just say 'not big'.

Comment: every adjective has a comparative *connotation*. Saying something is tiny *connotes* that it is lesser in size as something else. "If you ment to say little has a comparative"." then i can just reply that tiny also has a comparative (tinier). *Note as well* that "a little" is used differently in "a little happy/happier" than in "a little dog". Additionally I think "a tiny happy" is just as wrong as "a tiny happier". "little" has to be a noun in this adverbial phrase since due to the determinant "a".

Comment: Let me try with an example.  In a night sky, a planet, say Venus, appears as a missable TINY speck or dot, whereas moon appears as a unmissable little circle.  In other words, tiny is used when it is 'missable' or 'negligible', whereas little is 'unmissable'.  I referred to 'comparative' in the sense of how they are used.  Little elephant vs big elephant, little boy vs big man etc sorta thing often used with 'animates', while tiny hole vs large hole, tiny piece of land vs large tract of land etc.

Comment: . Now, what if you want to say it really did not make me much happier. In fact it nearly wasn't palpable that I was happier. It was nearly *missable*. would you then say "It made me a tiny happier"?  No, since it is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is interesting to note that *a little* cannot be seen in the same way in these examples:

> That is a little dog.
>   That is a little strange.

In the first sentence, *little* is an adjective, modifying *a dog*. The article belongs to *dog*, not to *little*.
In the second sentence, *a little* is a **noun**, used **attributively**.

*Little* is a word that can indeed be a noun, or a real adjective. A lot of nouns can be used attributively, but that doesn't make them adjectives or adverbs. *Little* acting as an adjective is a real adjective: it allows comparative and superlative clauses, and we can rewrite a sentence using a copula:

> A little dog => That dog is little.

When we use *a little* as a attributive noun, however, it no longer functions as an adjective! Compare these two examples:

> That man is a little strange.
>   That is a little strange man.

In the first sentence, *a little* modifies *strange* and we know nothing about the size of the man. The second sentence has the adjective *little* modifying *a man*.

Now, *tiny* is an adjective. It is not a noun. Never. *A tiny* is not "a tiny amount". Since it cannot function as a noun, it can also not function as an attributive noun. It is only ever an adjective:

> That is a tiny man => that man is tiny.

Notice how the article *a* belongs with *man*, not with *tiny*. 
Since we cannot use *tiny* as a noun, a sentence like

> *He is a tiny weird.

Is considered ungrammatical.

Comment: Finally someone with the same reasoning as I (the article "a" requires "little" to be a noun). Are you a native speaker? Because I am additionally interested in whether or not "a tininess" would be thought wrong/odd. I am convinced that "(a) little" in the given context has to be defined as "(a) little abstract measurement of". Therefore I think "a tininess" ought to work in the same way ("a tiny abstract measurement of").

Comment: @oerkelens This is interesting, but are you sure "a little" is a noun here? [This dictionary lists it as an adverb in this specific context, modifying an adjective, same as one of the other answers.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/little?q=a+little)

Comment: @Kirill: dictionaries are not always correct. It lists _little_ as an adverb, but then adds an **article** to it. I have only ever seen articles in English with nouns. Unless _little_ is the one and only exception to that rule ;)

Comment: @oerkelens Okay, fair enough, I'm not much of an expert here, just wanted to point that out (see also Matt Эллен's answer). IWWPWS, I wonder what Pullum would say.

Comment: @Kirill I would not say "a little" isn't an adverb/adverbial phrase but I still think it *consists* of an article and "little", which therefore has to be a noun (aslong as we are modifying an adjective). I assume oerkelens is of the same opinion. It is a noun just as "bit" and "lot" in "a bit" respectively "a lot".

Comment: @oerkelens Also, [Cambridge Grammar](https://archive.org/stream/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage) seems to say *a little* is a determinative.

Comment: I do not agree that "*a little* is a noun used attributively". Attibutive nouns are nouns that modify other nouns, not nouns that are used adverbially.

Answer (score -2):

It's for the same reason you can say **"many" eggs**, but you can **not** say **"many" milk** - one is "countable" and the other is "uncountable", as high-school English teachers label it.

"Happier" is **uncountable** - it's like a liquid.

You can't say "a tiny happier" for the same reason you can't say "a tiny milk".

You have to say "a tiny bit happier" or "a tiny bit of milk".

(or, use some similar deuncountablizing word, which depends on the uncountable substance in question, so, a tiny amount of milk, etc).

Similarly you can not say "a little eggs" - you have to say "very few eggs" (or a similar construction which can apply to discrete, quantified objects).

It's that simple!

Answer (score -2):

It is simply the way things have been done. Our brain has been accustomed to that specific way, so it eliminates other words that it is not used to being heard. Tiny is also even smaller than little, so it is technically used incorrectly anyways.