# Is it correct to say "tell it right"?

Tags: grammaticality

Could you advise if the phrase "tell sth. right" is correct grammatically?

Comment: My first intuition is that "right" needs to be derived into an adverb. Hence, "tell it rightly". Just as in "Answer the question correctly". ***Nevertheless*** one might have to take note that the actual _use_ of "tell it right" seems to convey that the speaker should "set it right". Here we often, if not always, find the phrase "set right a wrong" as in make it so that it becomes right. Therefor the adjective "right" might be correct. A native speaker or someone with reference would have to approve.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you're trying to say. Can you edit your question to provide a complete sentence using this construction, along with a paraphrase of the idea you're trying to get across? I think that might help you get a clear answer.

Comment: @AverageGatsby No; it doesnlt need _transforming_ into an adverb: it already exists as an adverb (see Joffysloffy's answer). Also, choosing the adverb _rightly_ here would be using it in an odd-sounding way (check the ratio of Google hits for "tell it right" vs "tell it rightly"). Flat adverbs are sometimes preferred (_Take it easily for a week or so_??).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are right. This is nearly the only situation in which I would consider using "right" well. And if you mean to insinuate something with your second example; no! I am not taking it easy untill I get an appropriate answer to my struggles with [this little nuisance](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222742/using-a-tiny-in-the-same-way-as-a-little/222757#222757) espacially as elaborated by me in the comment section of Dans comment, respectively until i have worked out something myself.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the dictionary (the New Oxford American Dictionary), it is correct. It says in particular:

> **right** |rīt|
>   adverb
>   **2** correctly: *he had guessed right.*
>   • in the required or necessary way; properly; satisfactorily: *nothing's going right for me this season.*

Answer (score 0):

"Tell it right," is common in AmE - usually as an admonition to someone relating an anecdote or telling a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Even Longman DCE (BrE) has right as an adverb and gives in no. 3

- to guess right (correctly)
- I thought you would be cross. -- You thought right.
- Everything's going right for him at the moment.
- It'll work out right in the end.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/right_3

My examples are from DCE in book form.