# that vs which vs what

Tags: grammar, differences, which-that, which-what, that

**Temporary reopen note**:

Pleas note that this other question here does not address *what* or compare it to *which* or *that*:

- [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which)

---

**Original Question**

- Which sentence would you use more, which is just simple wrong and why?

This is the speech, **that** my father wrote.
This is the speech, **which** my father wrote.
This is the speech, **what** my father wrote.

This is the speech, **that** my father wrote **down**.
This is the speech, **which** my father wrote **down**.
This is the speech, **what** my father wrote **down**.

Comment: Hi Koraiek, proofreading is off-topic on this site. Anyway, 'what' doesn't fit in your sentences!!

Comment: Drop the comma.  Otherwise, the first two are OK, the third would be considered "illiterate" in the US.  Normally the "down" would not be used in this context (though it's appropriate in other uses of "wrote").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. This is the speech, **that** my father wrote (down).
> 2. This is the speech, **which** my father wrote (down).
> 3. This is the speech, **what** my father wrote (down).

**The vocabulary**

The difference between *write* and *write down* is quite subtle. *Write down* implies that whatever was written existed in some other form before it was written down. So it might have been a fully formed idea, or someone may have read it out. *Write* on its own just means *write*. If we just use *wrote*, it gives the impression that it was actually the father's speech. However, if we use *wrote down* it might be someone else's speech that was written down. For example, a speech from the television.

**The grammar**

There are some problems with all of the sentences as they stand. These sentences almost definitely contain  so-called defining relative clauses, and so don't need a comma.

In defining relative clauses like this we can use either *which* or *that* as a relative word:

- This is the speech **that** my father wrote.
- This is the speech **which** my father wrote.

Here the word *speech* is the antecedent for the relative clause. There is a gap in the relative clause after the verb wrote where we would expect an object. We understand that gap as having the same identity as *the speech*:

- This is the speech<sub>(i)</sub> that my father wrote ____ <sub>(i)</sub>.
- This is the speech<sub>(i)</sub> which my father wrote ____ <sub>(i)</sub>.

Notice that the relative clauses here are modifying the word *speech*. They are turning it into one big noun phrase. "*This is the speech*" Which speech? "*The [**speech that my father wrote**]*".

However, we cannot use a relative clause with *what* to modify a noun in this way. We only use the relative word *what* when there is no antecedent for a relative clause:

- *This is **the speech what** my father wrote. (Ungrammatical - *what* with antecedent)
- This is **what** my father wrote. (Grammatical - no antecedent)

In the second sentence above, *what* does not have an antecedent. The relative does not have an antecedent. Instead the whole clause is the complement of the verb *BE*. The first example is ungrammatical because it uses *what* with an antecedent.

**The Original Poster's Question**:

The following sentence is incorrect in standard English because it uses an antecedent for the relative word *what*:

- This is the speech what my father wrote.

The following, however, are both fine:

- This is the speech that my father wrote.
- This is the speech which my father wrote.

In this case because there is a subject after the relative word (*that* or *which*), we can leave out the relative word:

- This is the speech my father wrote.

Hope this is helpful!

[**Note**: Some bogus usage guides say that *which* should not be used for defining relative clauses. This is rubbish. It is harmful to the study of Englsih grammar, and it has never been true. All the best writers have used both *which* and *that* for defining relative clauses.]

Comment: I found the following sentence: "Please note that only after this event window's Activated event will be fired which actually makes sense". I feel like "what" is a right choice in this case. Is author right about using "which"? It seems like here we have smth. like a hidden antecedent.