# Which vs that in this sentence: "Kaieteur Falls, which/that is 741 feet tall, is located in Guyana"

Tags: word-choice

I have this sentence: "Kaieteur Falls, which/that is 741 feet tall, is located in Guyana. My English teacher told me "that" would be correct. However, I strongly believe "which" would be correct. Could someone explain which one is correct?

Also, I am aware of threads such as [that vs which vs what](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223990/that-vs-which-vs-what) or others, and I have looked through those. I am fairly certain that "which" would be correct by reading these threads, but my English teacher thinks different.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. You can never use *that* after a comma like that.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. None. Can you please rollback the edit?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’ll leave that up to sumelic:) Anyways, I got in trouble at school for asking this on here, so I tried to delete it, but I couldn’t. Therefore, I tried to just edit away the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*which is 741 feet tall* is a nonessential relative clause, so it's correct to use *which* and a comma there. A nonessential clause (also known as a nonrestrictive clause) is one that just adds extra, nonessential information to the sentence and could be removed without changing the main meaning of the sentence: "Kaieteur Falls is located in Guyana." Your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer dangph! I completely agree, and I'm glad you could provide a more technical explanation for why this is correct.